# Eigenvalue of Momentum operator in Superposed Quantum states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, momentum, hilbert-space, superposition

Suppose we have normalised and orthogonal wavefunctions $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ as different solutions to the same equations with eigenvalues of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ for the momentum operator $\hat p$. Then, I construct a new wavefunction as $\psi = sin \theta \cdot\psi_1 + cos \theta \cdot \psi_2$.

Now $\psi$ is normalised. On applying the momentum operator, we have
$$\hat p\psi = sin \theta \cdot \lambda_1\psi_1 + cos \theta \cdot \lambda_2\psi_2$$
As far as I can tell, this  $\psi$ doesn't turn out to be an eigenfunction of $\hat p$. What is happening here? It should have an eigenvalue, right?

Comment: Nope, the superposition of two eigenvectors is not necessarily an eigenvector. It is only an eigenvector if the original ones were degenerate.

Comment: It's not clear why you think this should be an eigenfunction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as math is concerned, I cannot put it better then @Jannick did in the comment (which I've upvoted): no, a sum of eigenvectors with different eigenvalues is not an eigenvector.

As far as physics is concerned, $\psi_{1,2}$ admit the following interpretation: whenever you measure $p$ and the system is at one of these states, you will definitely get $\lambda_{1,2}$ as a result. The superposition $\psi$ is interpreted as follows: when measuring $p$ you could get either $\lambda_1$ or $\lambda_2$ with probabilities given by $\sin^2 \theta$ and $\cos^2 \theta$ respectively. Thus $p$ does not have a definite value when your system is at $\psi$, so $\psi$ it is not an eigenstate of $p$.

Comment: As far as the math is concerned, the superposition of eigenvectors is almost never an eigenvector. In fact the linear span of eigenvectors will be the set of all quantum states.

Comment: So what would be the equation for the value of $p$?

Comment: And do we now calculate $<p>$ the same as before, $<\psi \mid \hat{p} \mid \psi>$?

Comment: @Akshit sure. Its easy to show that it is equal to $\sin^2 \theta \cdot \lambda_1 + \cos^2 \theta \cdot \lambda_2$, so the probabilistic interpretation is correct.